# Excel: I need to check if a range of cells contain a number >90, and if so, return a number from another range of cells

Tags: excel-formula

Here's my data.  I'm actually trying to determine the day we hit the 90th percentile, so if you have a better idea, please suggest!!  For the example below, we hit 90% (Column D) on the 5th day (column A).  I'd like a formula that would return the number 5.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYWKE.png)

Sorry about the image. Im an extreme novice here and when I tried to enter my data in a table format, the columns wouldnt line up. I didnt realize an image was inappropriate but it's the only way I could convey my information.  This wasn't mentioned in any of the screens I clicked through to post the question, otherwise I wouldn't have.   I'll try to edit the table again and see if I can make it work.

Comment: Try `=MATCH(.9,D:D)-3`

Comment: That returned 2.  Wouldn't the formula need to include a "greater than or equal to 0.9"  or something similar?

Comment: [Why not images of Code and Sample Data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/285557#285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812).

Comment: Then change the `.9` to `90`

Comment: @Scott Craner I think match function will catch only when the value is equal to 90.

Comment: No. Without the third criterion it will find the time it is greater than but Les than the next.

Answer (score 1):

You got a negative vote because it is not appropriate to give examples in images.
but as far as I understand, the formula is simple and should look like this:

```
=COUNTIF(D2:D27,"<90")
```

If you wish the value of 90 to me included you should write:

```
=COUNTIF(D2:D27,"<=90")
```

If your excel is 2007 and under:

```
=COUNTIF(D2:D27;"<90")
```